# Isolated HTML Form not submitting

Tags: html

This code was working the other day but now the form won't even submit.
It is included inside another page but like I said it doesn't work when viewed as a solitary file. I likely just need some fresh eyes to see what the issue is and why the form won't submit at all.

```
<section>
    <div class="v-form">
        <h2 class="ArchiveFont">Login</h2>
        <form name="login" method="post" action="profile.php?action=login" class="v-form">
            <label for="login-email">Email</label>
            <input name="login-email" type="email" placeholder="Email">
            <label for="login-password-">Password</label>
            <input type="password" name="login-password" placeholder="Password">
            <?php if($loginerrorflag) echo "<small>$loginerrormsg</small>"; ?>
          <button type="submit" form="login">Login</button>
        </form>
    </div>
</section>

<section>
    <div class="v-form alternatingBKG">
        <h2 class="ArchiveFont">Register</h2>
        <form name="registration" method="post" action="profile.php?action=register" class="v-form">
            <label for="reg-email">Email</label>
            <input type="email" name="reg-email" placeholder="Email" 
            <?php if(isset($_GET['email']))
                echo "value=\"" . $_GET['email'] . "\""; ?>>
            <label for="reg-password-1">Password</label>
            <input type="password" name="reg-password-1" placeholder="Password">
            <label for="reg-password-2">Confirm Password</label>
            <input type="password" name="reg-password-2" placeholder="Confirm Password">
            <label for="f-name">First Name</label>
            <input type="text" name="f-name" placeholder="First Name">
            <label for="l-name">Last Name</label>
            <input type="text" name="l-name" placeholder="Last Name">
            <?php if($regerrorflag) echo "<small>$regerrormsg</small>"; ?>
          <button type="submit" form="registration">Register</button>
        </form>
    </div>
</section>
```

The code posted is the only code in the file. There is no JS so it makes no sense why the submit button won't trigger anything. Especially when it was working before. Please help :(

Comment: replace `<button type="submit" form="login">Login</button>` with`<input type="submit" value="Login">` and `<button type="submit" form="registeration">Register</button>` with`<input type="submit" value="Register">` , goodluck

Comment: Doesn't work and buttons have a default submit function for forms anyway so button vs input shouldn't matter.
Also for what its worth, pressing enter in the form doesn't submit either which shouldn't be affected by the button type.

Comment: as long as you are showing us the form code without any actions so i referred you to the input instead of buttons, but sorry what's exactly not working?  i tried it myself, as long as it take's me to another page, so no issues in the html, but if the problem isn't about submit, so it is depending on PHP file i'll give u asnippet

Comment: wtf. For me it won't even go to the action page. My PHP code is fine so it is just an HTML issue. Though if it works for you and you don't see any other HTML issues, maybe its an issue with my server config or something.

Comment: i added a snippet for you, give it a try =) and make sure to use a valid e-mail type to pass email's input validation =)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

here is a snippet with `<input type="submit" value="Login/Register">` use valid e-mail address and any password and try it

```html
<section>
    <div class="v-form">
        <h2 class="ArchiveFont">Login</h2>
        <form name="login" method="POST" action="profile.php?action=login" class="v-form">
            <label for="login-email">Email</label>
            <input name="login-email" type="email" placeholder="Email">
            <label for="login-password-">Password</label>
            <input type="password" name="login-password" placeholder="Password">
            <?php if($loginerrorflag) echo "<small>$loginerrormsg</small>"; ?>
          <input type="submit" value="login">
        </form>
    </div>
</section>

<section>
    <div class="v-form alternatingBKG">
        <h2 class="ArchiveFont">Register</h2>
        <form name="registration" method="post" action="profile.php?action=register" class="v-form">
            <label for="reg-email">Email</label>
            <input type="email" name="reg-email" placeholder="Email" 
            <?php if(isset($_GET['email']))
                echo "value=\"" . $_GET['email'] . "\""; ?>>
            <label for="reg-password-1">Password</label>
            <input type="password" name="reg-password-1" placeholder="Password">
            <label for="reg-password-2">Confirm Password</label>
            <input type="password" name="reg-password-2" placeholder="Confirm Password">
            <label for="f-name">First Name</label>
            <input type="text" name="f-name" placeholder="First Name">
            <label for="l-name">Last Name</label>
            <input type="text" name="l-name" placeholder="Last Name">
            <?php if($regerrorflag) echo "<small>$regerrormsg</small>"; ?>
          <input type="submit" value="Register">
        </form>
    </div>
</section>
```

Comment: So I copied and pasted it to give it a try even though I had already tried the swapping the two... and it worked.
But then I switched them back to buttons... and they still worked. So whatever you did made it magically start working again, even though using inputs wasn't the solution.